# Prevent SASS gulp compiler from adding a space before the "!important"

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

How can I prevent the space addition before `!important`? It is an important issue for Yahoo mail.

For example, the following code...

```
.align-block {
  @media (max-width: 699px) {
    width: 100%!important;
  }
}
```

...will be compiled like this...

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .align-block {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Please notice the space *before* the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would edit the gulpfile.js where you have the SASS task and add the line

```
.pipe(replace(' !important', '!important'));
```

This will replace what it matches on the output.